# Bulkify trigger by removing soql from for loop

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

I have belowtrigger which i need to optimize it to support bulkification.But getting error on line `List<Account> accounts = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Account Where Customer_ID__c =: custMap.get(inv.Id) limit 1];`

old trigger:

```
trigger UpdateSalesRepFromAccount on Invoice_CU__c (before insert, before update){
    for (Invoice_CU__c inv : Trigger.new){
        if( inv.Domain__c == 'JP2'){
            if( inv.Sales_Rep_Name__c == null || inv.Salesperson_Link__c == null ){
                List<Account> accounts = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Account Where Customer_ID__c=:inv.Customer_Number_Sold_To__c limit 1];
                if (accounts.size() > 0){
                    List<User> u = [Select ID, Name FROM User WHERE Id=:accounts[0].OwnerId limit 1];
                    if( u.size() > 0){
                        inv.Sales_Rep_Name__c = u[0].Name;inv.Salesperson_Link__c = u[0].Id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

New optimized code:

```
trigger UpdateSalesRepFromAccount on Invoice_CU__c (before insert, before update){
    map<id,String> custMap = new map<id,string>();
        set<id> ownid = new set<id>();
    for (Invoice_CU__c inv : Trigger.new){
        if( (inv.Domain__c == 'JP2')&&( inv.Sales_Rep_Name__c == null || inv.Salesperson_Link__c == null )){
            custMap.put(inv.id, inv.Customer_Number_Sold_To__c);
        }
    }
    if(custMap.size() > 0){
     List<Account> accounts = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Account Where Customer_ID__c =: custMap.get(inv.Id) limit 1];
     if (accounts.size() > 0){
         for(Account acc : accounts){
           ownid.add(acc.ownerId);  
         }
     }
    }
    if(ownid!=null){
     List<User> u = [Select ID, Name FROM User WHERE Id=:accounts[0].OwnerId limit 1];
    }
                    if( u.size() > 0){
                        inv.Sales_Rep_Name__c = u[0].Name;inv.Salesperson_Link__c = u[0].Id;
                    }



}
```

Comment: So did you have a question, or did you mean to answer your own question?

Comment: i have question. It might be some much better approach for optimizing my old trigger.I just gave attempt.

Comment: You haven't ported the logic correctly at all. You need to map by customer id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic approach should map each Account by its customer id. I fudged the names a bit here to make it easier to type on mobile, but it should be easy enough to figure out.

```
Set<String> numbers = new Set<String>();
for (Invoice__c record : trigger.new)
    if (jp2 && etc) numbers.add(record.CustomerNumber__c);
Map<String, Account> accounts = new Map<String, Account>();
for (Account record : [SELECT OwnerId FROM Account WHERE External__c IN :numbers])
    accounts.put(account.External__c, account);
for (Invoice__c record : trigger.new)
    if  (accounts.containsKey(record.CustomerNumber__c))
       record.UserLookup__c = accounts.get(record.CustomerNumber__c).OwnerId;
```

Also, look up trigger handlers. Find a pattern you like. Use it religiously.